# How do you embed a tflite file into an Android application?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

What are the step-by-step instructions for using a TFlite file and embedding it in an actual Android application? For reference, this is regression. Input will be an image, output should be a number. I have already looked at the TensorFlow documentation but they do not explain how to do it from scratch.

Comment: There is possibility to embed tflite model into C++ source code (by mapping data of tflite file into c++ array, and then creating tflite interpreter using it)
If you are interested in this, I can answer more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following steps are required to use TFLite in Android:

1. include the dependency 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+' to your build.gradle
2. Make sure files of type .tflite will not be compressed using the aaptOptions in your build.gradle
3. Make the model .tflite file available by putting it into your apps assets folder (To create one, right click `res` folder, click `res` > `New` > `Folder` > `Assets Folder`)
4. In your java class that will handle the inference, import the tflite interpreter
5. Load the model file as a MappedByteBuffer in your java class
6. Load the MappedByteBuffer into your TFLite interpreter
7. Convert input image to float ByteBuffer
8. Define output array matching the size of your output layer
9. Use the loaded TFLite interpreter to forward pass the input ByteBuffer through your model and write the prediction to your output array.

Let me know if something is unclear!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually resolved this problem months ago (in the end I just had the model run on server-side) but I'm certain your answer will be helpful for others who come across this issue.

Answer (score -2):

For Android applications, here is a quick example of using TF Lite for classification. You may be able to follow a similar structure as here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/demo/TFLiteImageClassifier.java